# Recreate a created Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity that writes some data to sharedpreferences after recieving it from a web service and also displays fragments. Those fragments use a method that needs those sharedpreferences to then populate the fragments layout.

The problem is that when the fragment initially gets created those shared preferences haven't been written yet and without them the fragment is blank. How can I recreate the fragment after I write to sharedpreferences?

Comment: Usually when you need to recreate anything on an activity or fragment that depend of certain logic, for example a callback from a service. You should put this logic on a method, then you should run this "logic" when you get the callback.

Comment: So get the data and then start the activity with the fragments?

Comment: The Larry's answer is correct, I think that recreate the fragment is not a best  way, anyway if you want, try this:  `FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to re-create the `Fragment`, that would be a very heavy operation.  Use `SharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` from your `Fragment` to register a callback to be notified when changes occur.  Then in your `Fragment`, provide an instance of something which implements `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.  See [`registerOnsharedPreferenceChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener)) and [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html).

Comment: Beautiful, so when shared preferences is updated the fragment would call it's method to populate rather than calling that method in the oncreateview. That makes a ton of sense I'll give it a shot.